# Is there any advantages storing cURL cookies? And relating questions

Tags: php, curl

I've got a `cURL PHP` script which works. It gets my schedule from my school site. Though there is one strange thing: On my webhost it creates the cookie.txt and on my localhost it doesn't.

- Why doesn't it create a cookie on my localhost? Any suggestions? Something with relative paths and wampserver?

And the questions that follows the latter:

- Is there any (speed) advantage of already being logged in on the school site (storing the cookie and thus saving an cURL request)?

I could for example check after the first cURL request if there is evidence in the response that I am already logged in.

If the answer to the above question is: *'no, this doesn't make the script faster'* I've got another question:

- Is it than best to specify only the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` option? With an empty value? So no cookie jar?

I can't give you my login information, though here is the script:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 
    'http://www.groenewoud.nl/infoweb/infoweb/index.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$tokenSource = curl_exec($curl);
print_r (curl_getinfo($curl));
if (!$tokenSource) echo 'token problem';

// Get the token from within the source codes of infoweb.
preg_match('/name="csrf" value="(.*?)"/', $tokenSource, $token);
$postFields = array(
    'user'     => $userNum,
    'paswoord' => $userPass,
    'login'    => 'loginform',
    'csrf'     => $token[1]);
$postData = http_build_query($postFields);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$tableSource = curl_exec($curl);
print_r( curl_getinfo($curl));
if (!$tableSource) echo 'post problem';

curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `/cookie/cookie.txt` means you'd need to have your cookie directory in the ROOT directory of your entire server. `cookie/cookie.txt` (note: NO leading slash) means the cookie directory would be a sub-directory of your script's CURRENT directory. E.g. your script is running in `/a/b/c/`, then you'd have `/a/b/c/cookie/cookie.txt`.

2) For speed advantages, there's no change in HTTP speeds - you're still stuck with the same pipes and transfer rates. But having the cookie initially MIGHT save you a few extra hits on the server to simulate the login-sequence, so would effectively be SLIGHTLY faster.

3) As for creating the cookies, that's entirely up to curl's settings. If you don't specify a cookie file or cookie jar, it won't create or look for the cookie file. Check the configuration/compile options between the two servers to see if one specifies some curl defaults that the other doesn't have.

4) str_pos WOULD be faster than a curl request. Think of it as the difference between looking in your fridge for some food versus driving to the grocery store. Fridge is local and therefore faster.

5) curlopt_cookiefile tells curl where to store new cookies. curlopt_cookiejar tells curl where to load cookies from when it first starts up. They CAN be different files, but don't have to be. If you'd like to keep some "clean" baseline cookies, then you use cookiejar = newstuff.txt, and cookiejar=baseline.txt. Once you've got an appropriate cookie environment set up, you reset cookiejar to newstuff.txt for subsequent curl runs.

Comment: Concerning your first answer: don't you mean /a/b/c/cookie/cookie.txt? Your third: Can you tell me more if I provide the cURL part of `phpinfo()`? Fourth: haha, ok, I'll look into my fridge. (Even if its a big (school's source code = 14k chars) fridge ?) Side note: scince I was browsing answers on cURL questions, and since I saw that you were online, I somehow knew that YOU would help me, haha.

Comment: Woops, yeah, sorry in the directory. In short, a leading `/` "roots" the directory reference at the top of the directory tree. No leading slash = relative path.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't seem to work on my windows+wamp+local server? Root works: so on my local machine it will create a cookie in c:/ (not where I want it to be). Another question: could you tell me which one will be faster? str_pos on 'My Schedule' or 'My Sch'? In other words: long string or small string? (they both will return one result)

Comment: for that length of string, don't even bother. you're chasing after microseconds worth of cpu time. Unless you're running a facebook-sized operation, it's utterly irrelevant.  For the cookie file, check that the webserver's userid has write permissions on both the file and the directory it's in.

Comment: But its WampServer on my local machine. Why does it create a cookie with an absolute path but not with a relative path? _"Secondly, please put ... at safe side."_ http://icfun.blogspot.com/2009/04/php-how-to-use-cookie-jar-with-curl.html Is he right?

Comment: The blog post is a load of BS. PHP runs on the server and your choice of browser or where you're browsing from has absolutely no effect on where the script is on the server or how it executes.

Comment: Could you answer the question about Wamp? Why do relative paths not steen to work on mij localhost=windows7?

Comment: Probably a permissions issue on the files/folders, but that's just a guess. No idea from the information you've provided. There's just too many variables in the mix.